# gradle release apk signature is not the same as IDEA signed apk

Tags: android, gradle

Firstly, I use IDEA to generate signed APK, but I try to switch my project as an Android Project using Gradle to generate signed APK, the signature is not the same. I use the same keystore and alias to package release APK.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Most probably one of your builds could be signed as debug.

Comment: Definitely yes, debug is different from the release one.